# How to setup ElasticSearch data backup with a Visual Studio solution and TFS?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, elasticsearch, tfs

During development of a .Net project using Visual Studio and TFS, I will be using a local copy of ElasticSearch and would like to be able to backup the indices as part of the solution in Windows for two reasons:

1. I will not be using a centralized/cloud-based server for ES at the beginning
2. I will be using different development machines and want to be able to 'get latest' of the ES db

Once ES is installed and running, what directories should I copy into my solution for backup?  This is probably the best solution, rather than trying to point ES to directories outside of its root, yes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're tied to system-side solution, [layout list](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/setup-dir-layout.html) should help. But I advice to take a look at ES [snapshot system](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-snapshots.html).